# How to query from a dataframe based on a datetime object with a timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a `dt` column of the form

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+01:00
```

I'm trying to query all datetimes corresponding to

```
2021-01-01 12:00:00+01:00
```

I know how to create a `datetime.datetime` object, but I can't figure out how to initialize tzinfo to a utc offset. How can I accomplish this or is there an easier way to do what I need?

Initializing datetime with tzinfo

Comment: Assuming `df` is your dataframe, can you `print(df.sample(10).to_dict("list"))` ?

Comment: if you're working with pandas, you can use pd.Timestamp, no need to use other libraries such as datetime etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `datetime` module does not provide a built-in way to directly initialize a `tzinfo` object with a UTC offset. However, you can use the `pytz` library to achieve this. Here's an example:

```py
import datetime
import pytz

# Define the UTC offset
utc_offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

# Create a custom timezone using pytz with the specified offset
custom_timezone = pytz.FixedOffset(utc_offset.total_seconds() // 60)

# Create the datetime object with the custom timezone
dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=custom_timezone)

# Print the datetime object
print(dt)
```

In this example, we use the `FixedOffset` class from `pytz` to create a custom timezone with the specified UTC offset. We convert the UTC offset to minutes and pass it to `FixedOffset()` to create the custom timezone object. Then, we use this custom timezone as the `tzinfo` argument when creating the `datetime` object.

Please make sure you have the `pytz` library installed in your environment. You can install it using `pip`:

```
pip install pytz
```

With `pytz`, you can handle more advanced time zone functionality, including handling daylight saving time transitions and working with a wider range of time zones.